# Find an inverse function of $\mathcal{G} $

Tags: functions, discrete-mathematics

Let $\mathcal{F} : \mathcal{P}(\mathbb{N}) \to \mathcal{P}(\mathcal{P}(\mathbb{N})) $  be defined as $\mathcal{F}(A) := \mathcal{P}(A)$

also let   Let $\mathcal{G} : \mathcal{P}(\mathbb{N}) \to \mathcal{F}(\mathcal{P}(\mathbb{N})) $  be defined as $\mathcal{G}(A) := \mathcal{F}(A)$

Give an inverse function to $\mathcal{G}$ or proove that it doesn`t exists.

1. what does this notation ':=' mean ? is it just an equality?
2. to prov that an inverse function exits it $\mathcal{F}$ has to be bijective. I understand how to prove injectiveness (every set of subsets can be just to one set). But how to proove the rest?

Comment: For 1. ":=" often is used to indicate something is defined this way. So for example, momentum $p$ is defined in terms of mass $m$ and velocity $v$ by the formula $p := mv$. For 2, you can define a function $\mathcal{F}(\mathcal{P}(\mathbb{N}))\to \mathcal{P}(\mathbb{N})$ and show that the properties of an inverse hold. That is $f: B\to A$ is an inverse of $g: A \to B$ if $(f\circ g)(x) = x$ and $(g\circ f)(x)=x$.

Comment: @DogeChan Ok thanks)